# settingWithCopyWarning pandas setting via index

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I am trying to set the value of a column in a dataframe by selecting via an index.

```
myindex = (df['city']==old_name) & (df['dt'] >= startDate) & (df['dt'] < endDate)
new_name = 'Boston2
df['proxyCity'].ix[myindex ] = new_name
```

In the above, I want to assign the value `Boston2` in the `proxyCity` column given the condition in myindex

```
C:\Users\blah\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:132: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
```

What is the correct way to do what I want to do without introducing problems as outlined in the documentation.

The answer in this link [using pandas to select rows conditional on multiple equivalencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22546425/using-pandas-to-select-rows-conditional-on-multiple-equivalencies#22546459) seems to do it the way I implemented it.

I'm not sure what is the right way to do this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To avoid double indexing, change

```
df['proxyCity'].ix[myindex ] = new_name
```

to

```
df.loc[myindex, 'proxyCity'] = new_name
```

It's more efficient (fewer `__getitem__` function calls) and in most cases, will eliminate the `SettingWithCopyWarning`.

Note, however, that if `df` is a sub-DataFrame of another DataFrame, it is possible for a `SettingWithCopyWarning` to be emitted 
even when using `df.loc[...] = new_name`. Here, Pandas is warning that modifying `df` will not affect the other DataFrame. 
If that is not your intent then the `SettingWithCopyWarning` can be safely ignored. For ways to silence the `SettingWithCopyWarning` see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40033471/190597).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mask`

```
mask = (df.city == old_name) & (df.dt >= startDate) & (df.dt < endDate)
new_name = 'Boston2
df.loc[:, 'proxyCity'] = df.proxyCity.mask(mask, new_name)
# Or
df.proxyCity.mask(mask, new_name, inplace=True)
```